# How to unzip Self Extracting Zip files in Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: c#, azure, 7zip, self-extracting, pkzip

I have a zip file(.Exe - Self-extracting zip file) that can be extracted using 7zip. As I want to automate the extraction process, I used the below C# code. It is working for the normal 7z files. But facing this issue 'Cannot access the closed Stream', when I trying to extract the specific self-extracting (.Exe) zip file. Fyi. Manually I ensured the 7zip command line version is unzipping the file.

```
using (SevenZipExtractor extract = new SevenZipExtractor(zipFileMemoryStream))
    {
        foreach (ArchiveFileInfo archiveFileInfo in extract.ArchiveFileData)
        {
            if (!archiveFileInfo.IsDirectory)
            {
                using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    string shortFileName = Path.GetFileName(archiveFileInfo.FileName);
                    extract.ExtractFile(archiveFileInfo.Index, memory);
                    byte[] content = memory.ToArray();
                    file = new MemoryStream(content);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The zip file is in Azure blob storage. I dont know how to get the extracted files in the blob storage.

Comment: Did you check your code would be able to unzip the file locally ? And knowing where the error is thrown would help, because from what you're telling us, the problem seems to be that you are trying to access an already closed stream.

Comment: Have you downloaded the entire file from Azure - and have it in memory - before this code is executed? Assuming you're dealing with an in-memory `MemoryStream` there should not be any issue with the fact that it came off Azure. I suspect the issue is occurring earlier than the code you posted, i.e., the contents of `zipFileMemoryStream` are incomplete. Also did you remember to reset the `Position` of that stream to `0`? That one gets me a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the workarounds that has worked for me. Instead of 7Zip I have used ZipArchive.

```
ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(myBlob);
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(destinationStorage);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destinationContainer);

foreach(ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries) {
  log.LogInformation($"Now processing {entry.FullName}");

  string valideName = Regex.Replace(entry.Name, @ "[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]", "-").ToLower();

  CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(valideName);
  using(var fileStream = entry.Open()) {
    await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
  }
}
```

**REFERENCE:**
[How to Unzip Automatically your Files with Azure Function v2](https://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/02/how-to-unzip-automatically-your-files.html)